# Более рациональная реализация алгоритма перебора, чтобы найти наименьшее положительное число, которое делится на все числа от 1 до 20

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, математика, теория-чисел

Есть задачка:

> 2520 - это наименьшее число, которое можно разделить на каждое из чисел от 1 до 10 без остатка.
>
> Найдите такое наименьшее положительное число, которое делится на все числа от 1 до 20?

Задачку эту я решил, написав плохо оптимизированный алгоритм полного перебора вариантов.

```
calculate = True
max_number = 20
min_number = 1
current_divisible = 2520
count = 0

while calculate:

   for i in range(2, max_number + 1):
       if current_divisible % i == 0:
          count += 1
          min_number = current_divisible
       else:
          count = 0
          break

   current_divisible += 1

   if count == max_number:
      calculate = False

print(min_number) # 232792560
```

Ответом этой задачки является число **232792560**, но мой алгоритм считает это очень долго. Около *15 минут*.

Никак не могу понять, как лучше оптимизировать данный код.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Least common multiple for 3 or more numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/282206/4279): `lcm(*range(1, 20))` выполняется мгновенно.

Comment: Очевидно, что при current_divisible += 1 если в одной итерации current_divisible делится на 20, то в следующих 19 итерациях current_divisible  делиться на 20 на будет. Одно current_divisible += 20 сократит время выполнения примерно в 20 раз.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Вообще-то говоря, вам надо просто искать наименьшее общее кратное для всех чисел от 1 до 20 :) Элементарно, никакого перебора, мгновенно.

Я могу набросать код на C или C++, Python не знаю.

Вот код - алгоритм Евклида для НОД, затем НОК...

```
long gcd(long m, long n)
{
    while(m && n) if (m < n) n %= m; else m %= n;
    return (m == 0L) ? n : m;
}

long lcm(long m, long n)
{
    return (m/gcd(m,n))*n;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    long Res = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i <= 20; ++i)
    {
        Res = lcm(Res,i);
    }
    cout << Res << endl;
}
```

Comment: Cи вроде смогу понять, так как знаю Java.

Comment: Смотрите; время счета - микросекунды...

Comment: Действительно, очень быстро отработало.

Спасибо!

Comment: Если хотите я могу переписать ваш код на python

Answer (score 2):

Эта задача решается вообще без программирования. Достаточно таблицы простых чисел и калькулятора.

Первое. Для того, чтобы делиться на числа из интервала от 1 до 20, искомое число должно делиться на все простые числа, которые встречаются среди делителей чисел из этого интервала.

То есть искомое число должно делиться на 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19.

Второе. Простые числа входят в делители чисел из интервала от 1 до 20 с разными степенями. Так, двойка встречается в степени 4 (`2**4==16`), тройка в степени 2 (`3**2==9`), все остальные простые числа только в первой степени.

Поэтому наименьшее общее кратное всех чисел из интервала от 1 до 20 должно делиться на 2 в четвертой степени, 3 в квадрате, числа 5,7,11,13,17,19 в первой степени.

Итого, получаем `16*9*5*7*11*13*17*19 == 232792560`.

Для вычисления НОК чисел от 1 до 1000 тоже особо программировать не требуется.

```
import math
import functools as fn
import operator as op

# Простые числа от 1 до 1000
primes=[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997]

def degree(p, n):
    "Возвращает максимальную степень числа p на интервале [1,n]"
    return math.floor(math.log2(n)/math.log2(p))

# Возведём каждое простое число в соответствующую степень и перемножим
fn.reduce(op.mul, map(lambda p: p**degree(p, 1000), primes), 1)
```

результат `7128865274665093053166384155714272920668358861885893040452001991154324087581111499476444151913871586911717817019575256512980264067621009251465871004305131072686268143200196609974862745937188343705015434452523739745298963145674982128236956232823794011068809262317708861979540791247754558049326475737829923352751796735248042463638051137034331214781746850878453485678021888075373249921995672056932029099390891687487672697950931603520000`

Кстати, предложенный скрипт работает для всех интервалов `[1, n]` при `n < 1009`. Например:

```
fn.reduce(op.mul, map(lambda p: p**degree(p, 10), primes), 1) ->  2520
fn.reduce(op.mul, map(lambda p: p**degree(p, 20), primes), 1) ->  232792560
fn.reduce(op.mul, map(lambda p: p**degree(p, 50), primes), 1) ->  3099044504245996706400
fn.reduce(op.mul, map(lambda p: p**degree(p, 100), primes), 1) ->  69720375229712477164533808935312303556800
fn.reduce(op.mul, map(lambda p: p**degree(p, 500), primes), 1) ->  
73239622318952846593863874519042298829761338251289259046349190034596307420803713394327759819891326985268312606648408875713314013313623337094312440663659803352061415560955398316253892220738945585450197206138869521568000
```

Comment: Решили перелопатить всё, что относится к простым числам и делимости? ;)

Comment: @MBo, как-то само пошло :)

Comment: можно оставить только `import math` и использовать `math.prod`

Answer (score 1):

Вот какой код я сделал на Python. Очень быстрый алгоритм, даже от 1 до 1000 считает моментально, а всё потому, что использовал поиск НОК для чисел от 1 до n, а не тупо перебор чисел, которые могут подойти.

```
def is_simple(x):

    """ Функция проверяет, простое ли число
    """

    if x == 2 or x == 3:
       return True
    flag = True
    for div in range(2, int(x**0.5+1)):
        if x % div == 0:
            flag = False
            break
    return flag


def final(lst_final, lst_temp):

    """ Функция распределяет получившиеся простые множители числа
        (из временного списка, обновляющегося при каждой итерации)
        в финальный список, числа из которого будут перемножаться
        и получаться нужный нам результат
    """

    if lst_final == []:                     # если финальный список пуст, значит это 1-ая итерация => добавляем все множители из временного списка
        lst_final.extend(lst_temp)
    else:
        for el in lst_temp:
            if el in lst_final:   # убедимся что элемент в финальном списке
                if lst_final.count(el) < lst_temp.count(el):    # нам нужно, чтобы в финальный список попало количество одинаковых множителей...
                    for _ in range(lst_temp.count(el) - lst_final.count(el)):  # ... не меньше, чем во временном списке, если их изначально меньше.
                        lst_final.append(el)                    # поэтому добавляем столько, чтобы их количество сравнялось
            else:                           # el not in lst_final
                lst_final.append(el)

lst_temp = []   # временный список простых множителей для каждого div in divisors
lst_final = []  # финальный список, останется только перемножить все числа в нем и вывести
divisors = [int(i) for i in range(int(input()), 1, -1)]  # наше задание - найти НОК от 1 до n из этого списка 

for div in divisors:
    lst_temp.clear()   # веменный список очищаем для каждого числа от 1 до n
    if is_simple(div): 
        lst_temp.append(div)
        final(lst_final, lst_temp)
    else:          # div - не простое число
        num = div  #переменная введена для удобства
        div_ = 2   # div_ - делитель для делителя div :)
        while div_ <= num:  
            if is_simple(div_) and num % div_ == 0:
                lst_temp.append(div_)
                num /= div_  # не забываем обновлять num
            else:
                div_ += 1
    final(lst_final, lst_temp)

k = 1   # переменная для удобства
for num in lst_final:  
    k *= num
print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
number=20
#determine the primes
primes=[]
for i in range(2,number+1):
    flag=True
    for k in primes:
        if i%k==0:
            flag=False
    if flag:
        primes+=[i]
#construction of the number
numbers=[]
for i in range(number,1,-1):
    offset=0
    for k in range(len(primes)):
        if math.log(i,primes[k-offset])%1==0:
            primes.pop(k-offset)
            numbers+=[i]
            offset+=1
numbers+=primes
#calc
res=1
for i in numbers:
    res*=i
print(res)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_number(n=14):
    number = 1
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        x = number
        while number % i != 0:
            number += x
    print(number)


print_number()
```

Comment: Код нужно хоть как-то пояснять.