# Как найти самое маленькое число, которое делится нацело на все числа от 1 до 20?

Tags: python-3.x, алгоритм

2520 - самое маленькое число, которое делится без остатка на все числа от 1 до 10.

Не понимаю, что в решении не так, в конце выдает ошибку о том, что память закончилась, но ведь нагрузка не такая большая ? Или я что-то путаю

```
max_multiple = 2520
dividers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,17,18,19,20]
dividers1 = []
t = True
while t:
    for i in range (2,21):
        if max_multiple % i == 0:
            dividers1.append (i)
        else:
            i -= 1
            max_multiple += 1

    if dividers1 == dividers:
        t = False

print (max_multiple)
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Более рациональная реализация алгоритма перебора, чтобы найти наименьшее положительное число, которое делится на все числа от 1 до 20](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/578710)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вместо отчаянного брутфорса (рабочего ли? я не вижу очистки списка множителей) лучше использовать то, что в школе проходили - наименьшее общее кратное

```
def gcd(a, b):
    while b > 0:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

def lcm(a, b):
    return a * b // gcd(a, b)     # integer division


d = 1
for i in range(2, 21): #last i=20
    d = lcm(d, i)
```

При решении вручную можно также выделить наибольшие степени простых множителей и перемножить их

Comment: Что такое брутфорс?

Comment: Перебор всех возможных решений, пока не попадётся правильное

Comment: Я правильно понял, что в d будет хранится значение предыдущего НОК?

Comment: Да, всё верно. НОК чисел от 2 до 3, потом чисел от 2 до 4, потом от 2 до 5 и т.д.

Comment: `gcd` можно импортировать из `math`, или из `fractions` в более ранних версиях

Answer (score 1):

```
def nod (a,b):
    while b > 0:
        a,b = b, a % b # Формула НОД
    return a

def nok (a,b):
    return a*b // nod(a,b) # Нок по формуле а*b // на нод a,b

d = 1 # В нем будет хранится значение предыдущего НОК
for i in range (2,21): #Перебераем делители
    d = nok(d,i) # Ищем их НОК
print (d)
```